# Best way to encrypt a file, and keep it handy

Tags: authentication, encryption, passwords

I am using dozens of different web services, and I keep a password file in a remote Linux machine. The file contains my usernames, passwords and answers for security question.

This server happens to be offline to often, and I'm looking for a way to keep the password file on my own computer, or on a service like [DropBox](http://getdropbox.com). Obviously, I want to keep the file encrypted, but handy - I want to be able to print its contents using one shell (or cygwin) command, perhaps using a passphrase.

Any good ideas how to do it?

Comment: Trying to think hard to consider this "programming related".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use GPG's symmetric option to encrypt files with pass-phrases.

```
gpg --symmetric filename
```

That will result in an encrypted file named `filename.gpg`. To redirect the output to STDOUT instead of a `.gpg` file:

```
gpg --symmetric -o - filename
```

You can later decrypt the file with:

```
gpg --decrypt filename.gpg
```

Comment: I have read about gpg, but how can you pass the output to the standard output rather than to the .gpg file?

Comment: OK, It's the usual "-o". I should have googled harder (trying "stdout", not only "standard output"). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use [PasswordSafe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/relatedprojects.shtml) encrypted files in exactly this configuration. GUIs are available for Windows/Mac/Unix/Java. [cliPSafe](http://waxandwane.org/clipsafe.html) gives it a command line interface.

THe original code was written by Bruce Schneier, well known in the security world, but I've never used cliPSafe.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted GPG solves the problem. Using the gpg command directly for encrypting text files may be a bit cumbersome though, especially as you would often decrypt the file to a seperate file, add some text (passwords in this case) and the reencrypt it (which will possibly expose your unencrypted data).

Vim has a very good plugin called [gnupg](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=661) for trasparently handling encrypted files using GPG. Using this plugin the unencrypted data will never be written to disc and you can just treat it as any other file (except for the passphrase question popping up of course).

Comment: Wow, that's great. Found the link. Thanks!